# Should it always be "when someone did action X someone else HAD done action Y?"

Tags: grammar, tenses, sentence, time

I have encountered this sentence: "She was dancing **when** he started to play music"

From what I know, it should be: "She **had been** dancing when he started to play music"

My question is: is the first sentence grammatically correct? I know that in a daily conversation people might not be aware of it, but in a formal, correct language, should not it be only like sentence two?

Thank you!

Comment: The grammar is fine. The 2 variants communicate a little differently.

Comment: The second implies that she might not have still been dancing when he started to play, while the first implies that she was still dancing when he started.

Comment: No, it should not **always** be that. It's quite fine to say *when someone did action X someone else **did** action Y*. However, that comment is in response to the title of the question—which is different from the body of the question. It's not clear exactly what you're asking.